# Disparity between file-nr and netstat

Tags: linux, files, proc, socket, netstat

```
> netstat | grep :389 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l
2116

> cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr 
1920  0  3178047
```

how can a subset of the number of  tcp connections be more than the total number of file handles allocated in the system?